# Request response doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, post

Here is my **JSON** function:

```
function createjson(){
  var json='{"jsondata":[[';
  $("#kup td").each(function(){
  if($(this).html()!="")
  {
    json+= parseInt($(this).html())+",";
    if($(this).index()%5==0 && $(this).index()!=0){
      json=json.substring(0,json.length-1);
      json+="],["
    }                       
  }             
 });
json=json.substring(0,json.length-3);
json+="]]}";
console.log(json); //-> works fine.
return json;
};
```

The **AJAX** part:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"x.php",
    data: createjson(),
    contentType: "application/json",
dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
        alert("done"); //->works
    }
  });           
});
```

The **PHP** part:

```
<?php
   header('Content-type: application/json');
   echo "<pre>";
   echo    $_POST['jsondata'];
   echo "</pre>";
?>
```

So, the "alert" works but when check the response in console, it returns only "`<pre></pre>`"

any solution?

Comment: json data must not contain the <pre> elements

Comment: Have you used your developer tools to inspect the request your JS makes to the server? What is sent for the `jsondata` key? Also, if you make an object with the key/value pairs you want to send to your server you don't need to create a JSON string yourself, jQuery will parameter-ize for you.

Comment: also check your json sent for validity e.g. with jsonlint

Comment: @Jasper `console.log(json);` part works fine. json validator gives no error. i send this for ex: `{"jsondata":[[10,13,18,27,37,48]]}`

Comment: @WhoCares What about doing a `var_dump($_POST['jsondata']);` in PHP?

Comment: @jasper it returns `<pre>NULL</pre>`

Comment: You have specified a `dataType` of json, yet you are not returning a JSON object from `x.php` — that is reason of your error.

Comment: data must be plainobject or string maybe not create the json before?

Comment: @WhoCares So the data isn't being sent or not being sent properly. I recommend just creating a JS object of key/value pairs and using that for the `data` you send.

Comment: The data option can contain either a query string of the form key1=value1&key2=value2, or an object of the form {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}. If the latter form is used, the data is converted into a query string using jQuery.param() before it is sent. This processing can be circumvented by setting processData to false. ... http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: so leave the quotes of "jsondata"

Comment: @abimelex i did. returned "null"

Comment: @terry I used `json_encode` (I think u'r talking about that) and it returned null either.

Comment: @jasper mate, I have no idea key/value pairs. If you can give a little example?

Comment: do it like this: " data: {status: status, name: name}, " or put plain js array there instead of json. jsonencode is needed on serverside maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The data option can contain either a query string of the form
>   key1=value1&key2=value2, or an object of the form {key1: 'value1',
>   key2: 'value2'}. If the latter form is used, the data is converted
>   into a query string using jQuery.param() before it is sent. This
>   processing can be circumvented by setting processData to false

. from [jquery API doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

I didn't tested it but should give the intense how to change structure, give it a try:

```
function createdata(){
  var data;
  $("#kup td").each(function(){
    if($(this).html()!="")
    {
      data.push( parseInt( $(this).html() ) );
      //...                    
    }             
  });
console.log(data);
return data;
};

$("#button").click(function(){
  var data = createdata();
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"x.php",
    data: {createjson:data},
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
        alert("done"); //->works
    }
  });           
});
```